# SwiftUI: How to dismiss a modal sheet and then execute a navigationlink together

Tags: ios, swift, modal-dialog, swiftui, navigationlink

I've got an onboarding process with a welcome view that has two buttons that open modal sheets for signup and login.

Once signup is completed, the button should close the modal view for Signup and transition to another Dashboard view.

How can I close the modal and then execute the navigationlink to the dashboard view?

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct Signup: View {    

@State private var isAuthCompleted: Bool = false
@State private var isShowingAlert = false
@State private var localMsg: String = ""

@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

.
.
.


// signup button

        NavigationView {

            VStack {

                NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(),
                               isActive: self.$isAuthCompleted) {
                                Text("")
                }

                Button(action: {

                    Auth.auth().createUser(
                    withEmail: self.email,
                    password: self.password
                    ) {
                        authResult, error in
                        if let e = error {

                            print(e.localizedDescription)
                            self.localMsg = e.localizedDescription
                            self.isShowingAlert = true

                        } else {

                            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() // modal sheet dismiss                                
                            self.isAuthCompleted = true // navigationlink execution


                            }

                        }

                }) {

                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Sign Up")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .cornerRadius(20.0)

                }
                .alert(isPresented: $isShowingAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Wait A Minute"), message: Text(self.localMsg), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
                }

            }
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)

        }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the method to show a modal and execute an action on dismiss. It should look similar to this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Signup: View {

  // Property to keep track of your modal state
  @State var isPresented = false

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        Button(action: {
           // Show / hide the modal view with toggle()
           self.isPresented.toggle()
        }, label: {
           // Your button label
        })
          .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, 
                 onDismiss: {
                  // What happen when your modal dismiss
          }) {
            // Modal view that opens to be declared here
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```